# Conditions for an operator to be an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm looking at two problems that start by saying there's an operator $P$ on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$ such that $P^2$ = $P$. Now the two problem statements split, giving two different conditions, but the details don't matter for my question.

I'd like to know what's wrong with the following reasoning.

Suppose $v \in (\text{null}P) \cap (\text{range}P)$. Then $Pv = 0$, but also $Pv = v$, and thus $v = 0$. So $(\text{null} P) \cap (\text{range} P) = \{0\}$. But that means that $V = (\text{null} P) \oplus (\text{range} P)$, since $\text{dim} V = \text{dim} \ \text{null} P + \text{dim} \  \text{range} P$.

But then $P = P_{\text{range} P}$, that is, it's the orthogonal projection onto its own range.

This is supposed to be proven in both problems, but they supply additional conditions, and that makes me think I must be mistaken somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P = P^2$, then $P$ is a *projection* (onto its range), but it is not necessarily an *orthogonal projection* (onto its range). In fact, $P$ is an orthogonal projection if and only if $P = P^T$ (or, over $\Bbb C$, $P = P^*$).

In particular, the nullity and range are orthogonal complements to each other if and only if $P = P^T$.  What this means is that we do have $V = \operatorname{null}(P) \oplus \operatorname{range}(P)$ as *vector spaces*, but we do *not* have $V = \operatorname{null}(P) \oplus \operatorname{range}(P)$ as *inner product spaces*.

As a potentially helpful counterexample, consider the map $T(x,y) = (x+y,0)$.

Comment: Thanks. The source of my confusion was that I thought that, since I can make a basis such that a part of it spans the null space, and the other part spans the range, I could also make an orthonormal basis with that property. Which is wrong. Gram-Schmidt will orthonormalize the first part, but mix it into the other part if the two spaces are not orthogonal complements.

Comment: Right; once you "mix" the two spaces, you get something that is neither in the range nor the null-space.